# I want to insert subelement to a subelement in xml tree using Java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Dekkey {
    String keyVal;
    String kek1;

    public String getKek1() {
        return kek1;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setKek1(String kek1) {
        this.kek1 = kek1;
    }

    public String getKeyval() {
        return keyVal;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setKeyval(String inpKey) {
        this.keyVal = inpKey;
    }
}
```

This is my code snippet, where I want to insert a sub-element called userkey to the sub-element kek1. How can I do that?

How to insert attribute value for those sub-elements? I have another class called `MarshDemo` in which an object of `Dekkey` is created and then `setkeyVal()` function is called by passing value to the function.

The output looks like this:

```
<Dekkey keyVal="xer">
    <kek1 keyVal="biv">
        <userkey keyVal="wed">
        </userkey>
    </kek1>
</Dekkey>
```

Comment: Check out the @XmlPath extension in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy): blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html.  In your example how do the 3 values `xer`, `biv`, and `wed` in the XML document relate to the 2 properties in your `Dekkey` class?

Answer (score 0):

I have omitted the getters and setters for brevity, this is what your should look like.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Dekkey {
    @XmlAttribute
    String keyVal;

    Kek1 kek1;
}

@XmlElement(name="kek1")
public class Kek1 {
    @XmlAttribute
    String keyVal;

    UserKey userkey;
}


@XmlElement(name="userkey")
public class UserKey {
    @XmlAttribute
    String keyVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

**Dekkey**

Below is how you could map your use case using MOXy's `@XmlPath` extension (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html).

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement(name="Dekkey")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Dekkey {

    @XmlAttribute
    String keyVal;

    @XmlPath("kek1/@keyVal")
    String kek1;

    @XmlPath("kek1/userkey/@keyVal")
    String userKey;

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB (JSR-222) provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html).

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Dekkey.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum16248263/input.xml");
        Dekkey dekkey = (Dekkey) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(dekkey, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Dekkey keyVal="xer">
   <kek1 keyVal="biv">
      <userkey keyVal="wed"/>
   </kek1>
</Dekkey>
```